# Can I turn on service broker on all my databases?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I have a multi-tenant database server with over 200 databases.Can I turn on service broker on all these databases without effecting the performance of the server? Does this have a big impact on the server ?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but I figure that there must be some overhead in having that setting enabled for a db otherwise it would be on by default. If it were me, I'd only enable it if necessary.

Comment: @BenThul it **is** on by default.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Hmm... I don't know about that: on my local development copy, model has is_broker_enabled set to 0 and I know that I didn't set it that way explicitly.

Comment: @RemusRusanu ..we have atleast over 500+ databases across 6 servers and we have been selectively turning on  service broker and not seen any issues so far. We want to turn service broker on all databases now and want to make sure that it doesnt eat up the memory.We will be using service broker on 50% of the databases and the message volume will be very low too

Comment: @user370844: monitor the normal [SQL Server parameters](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/#usage_counters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Activating Service Broker on a database requires exclusive access to the database, in other words all existing connections will need to be terminated and non committed transactions will need to be rolled back. You would need to query sys.databases and set up a Dynamic SQL Statement to loop through the databases to activate Service Broker on all of them. There isn't a server level command to activate Service Broker on all databases.

Activating Service Broker will not have an impact on the Server until you begin creating Message Types, Contracts, Queues and Services on those Queues and begin accumulating data.

Here is the code to activate Service Broker, again beware, because it will terminate all connections and rollback all non committed transactions.

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET ENABLE_BROKER 
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE 
GO
```

Before activating Service Broker, you can run a quick query to see if it's already been activated.

```
SELECT is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'MyDatabase'
```

This is a great link for a basic Service Broker walkthrough that I found very useful when implementing Service Broker at my last client.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/service-broker-foundations-workbench/

Comment: Thanks for the info.We have implemented Service broker but thinking of enabling on all the 200+ databases on the server.Only a few would have messages and the rest would be idle.